# how to build progress bar with precentage in python and js

Tags: javascript, python, css, testing, preloader

i have a GUI in js css and html, and a server in python. the server is running tests automatically and i want to show the user how many tests has been done. each test is located in a  a configuration file that is sent to the server (in case of multiple configuration files, all sent at once, and each configuration file can contain multiple tests)
i thought about summing all the tests in each conf file (its a json so can just take the test list len) on all conf files before i start the testing to know how many tests i have in total and then every time i finish a test i use a thread to send the GUI an update of how many tests has been done.
is there any other way which is more efficient and cost less runtime?